# regarding the cholesky decomposition of a crossproduct of a matrix

Tags: r, statistics, regression, correlation

With respect to the following R implementation

```
Y %*% solve(chol(crossprod(Y)))
```

I can see it aims to perform cholesky decomposition over the **Y'Y**, and then multiplied by **Y** again.

What is it used for in the data processing? I do not quite understand the underlying mechanism.

Comment: It is the Q matrix in the QR decomposition of Y.   Google QR decomposition for more information.